# I have a ASUS USB-AC51, but it doesn't have AP mode. Is that the adapter or driver problem?

Tags: wifi

I run this command on my Fedora:

```
iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A 8
```

It showed my adapter doesn't support AP mode. But I checked this [Asus USB-AC51](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-AC51) and [Driver capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers#Driver_capabilities), the website showed mt76 supported AP mode. Is that driver or adapter problem?

```
    Supported interface modes:
     * managed
     * monitor
Band 1:
    Capabilities: 0x17e
        HT20/HT40
        SM Power Save disabled
        RX Greenfield
        RX HT20 SGI
```

My adapter is at Port 12.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 22, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 22, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 12: Dev 23, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=mt76x0u, 480M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 21, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 21, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 21, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but where did you find that this adapter has this hardware capability?  All sources I found *DO NOT* say it has this capability in hardware, so ergo, it does not, so it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got for ASUS USB-AC51 on Arch Linux kernel 5.10.73:

```
$ iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A 8
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
                 * mesh point
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
```

Also, AP created by NetworkManager works fine (both 2.4G & 5G).

A possible issue may be the older kernel. [mt76x0e supports AP since kernel 5.0](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4cb23b650a59b042f647d09d16d527d026b2d2f2), and [all mt76 drivers declare AP support since kernel 5.5](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0eb8c104fd8dfc2a8636b09b3f908170f7c9d037).